# multiple independent implicits in Scala

Tags: scala, implicit

Scala is cool.  But also at times exceedingly frustrating due to lots of seemingly arbitrary restrictions as well as things that don't work like I expect.

In this case, I wrote an argument-parsing library in Scala.  It has this function:

```
def option[T](
  name1: String, name2: String = null, name3: String = null,
  name4: String = null, name5: String = null, name6: String = null,
  name7: String = null, name8: String = null, name9: String = null,
  default: T = null.asInstanceOf[T],
  metavar: String = null,
  choices: Seq[T] = null,
  aliases: Map[T, Iterable[T]] = null,
  help: String = "")
(implicit convert: (String, String, ArgParser) => T, m: Manifest[T]) = {
  optionSeq[T](nonNullVals(name1, name2, name3, name4, name5, name6,
    name7, name8, name9),
    metavar = metavar, default = default, choices = choices,
    aliases = aliases, help = help)(convert, m)
}
```

Essentially, this declares a normal option argument of a given type.  There's an implicit function which gets filled in with a default converter that is appropriate to the type.  There's also an implicit manifest, which is necessary because I need to be able to condition on it for certain things.

This worked until I tried to actually supply a non-default converter.  As written, you can't just supply the converter, but also have to supply a manifest, which I don't know how to do, and anyway it's horribly ugly -- manifests are a nasty kludge designed to work around a major piece of brokenness in the JVM, and shouldn't be exposed to the end user.

I already know that Scala doesn't let you mix implicit and non-implicit arguments in a single argument list -- IMO an arbitrary and unnecessary restriction, but so be it.  So I tried splitting the implicit argument list into two separate argument lists, each with one implicit.  No luck -- Scala also seems to prevent you from having more than one implicit argument list (another seemignly arbitrary restriction).

I have zero idea how to work around this.  Suggestions?

Also, are there any current attempts to fix some of these restrictions on implicits in future Scala versions (and/or come up with a more invisible way of working around type-erasure brokenness than manifests, which IMO are butt-ugly)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a very awkward method.  Nine explicit name arguments?  Implicit selection of conversion function?  I'm not sure that manifests are the worst problem here.

Anyway, you can

```
class Converter[T: Manifest](val f: (String, String, ArgParser) => T) {
  def m = manifest[T]
}
implicit def function_to_converter[T: Manifest](f: (String, String, ArgParser) => T) =
  new Converter { def apply(s1: String, s2: String, ap: ArgParser) = f(s1,s2,ap) }
}
```

and then use that instead of the two arguments you've got.  Define all your default converters like

```
implicit val convert_to_int: Converter = (s1: String, s2: String, ap: ArgParser) => ...
```

and then if the user needs to explicitly fill one in, they can just supply the function and have it implicitly converted.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. It appears awkward because I'm trying to work around a Scala non-feature.  I want you to be able to declare one or more names, plus some named arguments, like this: `option[Int]("ngram", "n-gram", default = 3, help = """something""")`.

Answer (score 3):

You can always get the `implicit` of type `T` in context with `implicitly[T]`. So if you need to write explicitly the implicit `Manifest[T]` that the compiler would have supplied, you can do that with `implicitly[Manifest[T]]`.

This works anytime you want to supply an argument in an implicit parameter list, and leave the other unchanged, just use implicitly[TheTypeOfTheImplicit] for argument you don't want to change.

For Manifests, `Predef` happens to have a shortcut for that, which is just `manifest[T]` (which is just `implicitly[Manifest[T]]`)

Note : `implicitly` is not magic, it is just `def implicitly[T](implicit e: T) = e`, in `Predef.`

Comment: Thanks.  I'd like to avoid having to make the user fill in the manifest explicitly, since it's really an implementation feature; that's why I accepted the other answer.